# UIView frames change every-time upon ViewController loading

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimage, constraints

I have a `UIView` on xib and when I check it's frame on `viewDidLoad` it says:

```
  - some : <UIView: 0x7fcc3948b8a0; frame = (56.3333 122; 262.333 262.333); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x600003a62060>>
```

After calling `layoutIfNeeded()`, right after the previous log, it says:

```
  - some : <UIView: 0x7fcc3948b8a0; frame = (56.5 121.917; 262 262.5); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x600003a62060>>
```

And, on `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`, the frame is:

```
  - some : <UIView: 0x7fcc3948b8a0; frame = (62 122; 290 289.5); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600003477420>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600003a62060>>
```

Why does it matters to me? Because I set a `UIScrollView` inside that view and an `UIImage` with zoom inside of the `UIScrollView`, which makes the image correct zoom frame to break.

How can I fix that?

Comment: You need to be much more detailed about what you're doing. You *"have a UIView on xib"* ... show how you have that view constrained and how you're loading and adding it as a subview. *"on viewDidLoad"* ... do you mean in the controller where you've added the view from the xib? Or is your xib a view controller? How are you trying to *"set a UIScrollView inside that view and an UIImage with zoom inside of the UIScrollView"*?

Comment: In my UIViewController i've added a UIView (1) which has a top, align center x, equal width (to superview) and ratio 1:1 constraints. He has a UIScrollView as a subview, which have a top, bottom, leading and trailing constraints. This UIScrollView have a UIView set as a subview and he has top, bottom, leading, trailing and equal width, height (to UIView num.1) constraints. Inside this UIView I have a UIImage without any constraints. Hops this understandable. haha

Comment: Why don't you add constraints to UIImageView?

Comment: Because the image is zoomed by data I get from the WS and when adding constrains to it, it prevent it from getting zoomed. The UIScrollViewDelegate has method called 'viewForZooming' which I return the image and the image gets zoomed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple example which may help you on your way.

I have a `1200 x 1200` image, with grid lines at 100-pixels. The green rectangle is at `600, 200` and is `300 x 400` pixels. That will be my target "zoom to" rectangle.

[image]

Of course, my scroll view will not have an exact `3:4` ratio, so the green rect will end up centered in the scroll view when zoomed.

Here it is on an iPhone 11 Pro Max. I'm using a navigation controller, so you see the Nav Bar at the top... the view background is white... the scroll view is constrained to the view's safe area with 8-pts on each side:

[image]

Here's the code to generate that:

```
class ScrollTestViewController : UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    
    let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let v = UIScrollView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .cyan
        return v
    }()
    
    let zoomImageView: UIImageView = {
        let v = UIImageView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        return v
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        guard let img = UIImage(named: "img1200x1200") else {
            fatalError("Could not load image!!!")
        }
        print(img.size)
        zoomImageView.image = img
        
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        
        // add the scroll view
        self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
        
        // add contentView to scroll view
        scrollView.addSubview(zoomImageView)
        
        // respect safe-area
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        // we're going to constrain the zoomImageView to the scroll view's content layout guide
        let scg = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // constrain scrollView Top / Leading / Trailing / Bottom to view (safe-area)
            //  with 8-pts on each side
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            
            // constrain zoomImageView Top / Leading / Trailing / Bottom to scroll view's Content Layout Guide
            zoomImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scg.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            zoomImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scg.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            zoomImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scg.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            zoomImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scg.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            // constrain zoomImageView's width and height to the width and height of the image
            zoomImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: img.size.width),
            zoomImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: img.size.height),
            
        ])
        
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.25
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 10.0

        scrollView.delegate = self

    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        // we need to set the "zoom to" rect *after* auto-layout
        //  has finished everything else
        let r = CGRect(x: 600, y: 200, width: 300, height: 400)
        scrollView.zoom(to: r, animated: false)
    }
    
    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return zoomImageView
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Would you mind helping me in private with that and than of course publish the solution?

Comment: It's working but for some reason in iPhone 6s the image is smaller inside the scroller compare to other devices, what could be the problem?

Comment: @YossiTsafar - You'll have to be a bit more clear... Here's how it looks when I run that on an iPhone 6s (simulator): https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLKgU.png